# Generic method in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Hello dear developers and engineers! I stumbled upon the usage of a generic method. I don't have to use generic. However, I preferred it.
I use Unity3D.
MageAA class has access to EnemyID class and Player controller class. PlayerController class has no access to others.
My point is to create a generic method in PlayerController class. Then call that method in MageAA with EnemyID as an argument. Here what I've. How can I make it work?
Thank you!

```
public class MageAA : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject selectedTarget;

    PlayerController controller;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<PlayerController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        selectedTarget = controller.SelectPointedObject<EnemyID>();
    } 
}



public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject SelectPointedObject<T>() where T: class
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            RaycastHit[] hits = RaycastAllSorted();
            
            if (hits.Length > 0 && hits[0].transform.GetComponent<T>() != null)
            {   
                return hits[0].collider.gameObject;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you do that: `public GameObject SelectPointedObject(EnemyID id);` ?

Comment: ThePlayerController class does not have access to EnemyID. Generally, the reason I chose to use generics is I might use other Classes instead of EnemyID in the future.

Comment: You can pass interface and deriver EnemyID and other classes from this interface

Comment: Yep, that's a standard way of solving circular dependency. As I don't have a habit of using generics, I wanted to use it. I guess it's not just the case. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Dear Friends :) I've finally found the reason it did not "work". All the generic part was fine. The problem was I used the assignment line under the `FixedUpdate` function which quickly replaced `selectedTarget` with `null` even after the successful assignment. Thank you all! Have a GREAT day! :) <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public interface ICharacter 
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Health { get; set; }
}
public class Character : ICharacter
{
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public int Health { get; set; }

    public string GetOrSetName(string name) 
    {   
        if (Name != null)
            Name = name;
        return Name;
    }
}

public class Hero : Character
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Health { get; set; }
}
public class NPC : Character
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
public class NamerClass
{   
        public Character Character { get; set; }
    
        public string GetOrSetName<T>(string text)  where T :  Character, new ()
        {
            return Character.GetOrSetName(text);
            
        }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
Hero hero = new Hero();
            NPC npc = new NPC();
            
            NamerClass genericNamer = new NamerClass();

            genericNamer.GetOrSetName<Hero>("SUPER MARIO");

            genericNamer.GetOrSetName<NPC>("POTION MARKET");
}
```

"May be this gives you an idea"